Подскажите, где я допустил ошибку?
if registration_password = None:
    print ("Для начала необходимо пройти регистрацию")
    registration_password = str(input("Введите пароль для регистрации"))
elif:
    login_password = str(input("Введите пароль для входа"))
if registration_password = login_password:
    print ("Вы успешно вошли в систему")
else: 
    print ("Пароль указан не верно")


А как вы узнали, что у вас ошибка?

В логике и знании языка. Пройдитесь построчно по вашему коду (всего-то 9 строк, из них смысловых 4) и найдите ошибки сами

Классическая опечатка в операторе сравнения?  Вместо == стоит =?


Конструкция str(input()) является лишней, поскольку input изначально возвращает строковое значение, тоесть тип данных str.

В случае с registration_password = None и registration_password = login_password необходимо писать ==, поскольку == является оператором сравнения, а = - оператором присваивания. А в случае с registration_password = str(input("Введите пароль для регистрации")) как раз применён оператор присваивания.

elif дословно переводится как else if, т. е. означает ("если не истинно предыдущее условие, является ли конкретно это истинным"). В данном случае код не выполняется, поскольку не написано условие для elif. Здесь будет уместнее писать else.

Для сравнивания переменной со значением None лучше использовать оператор is:
if registration_password is None:


Надеюсь, что ответ понятен. Ниже готовый код:
registration_password = None
if registration_password is None:
    print("Для начала необходимо пройти регистрацию ")
    registration_password = input("Введите пароль для регистрации")
    login_password = input("Введите пароль для входа ")
else:
    login_password = input("Введите пароль для входа ")

if registration_password == login_password:
    print("Вы успешно вошли в систему")
else: 
    print("Пароль указан не верно")


Ну тогда стоит ещё добавить, что для проверки является ли переменная None стоит использовать оператор is

Верно, забыл упомянуть

@underv0lt, вы всегда можете править свои ответы: для этого достаточно воспользоваться ссылкой [edit] под текстом вашего ответа. Важную информацию лучше включать непосредственно в исходное сообщение.
